# CSS animation is "trembling" on cellphones. getComputedStyle not getting accurate values

Tags: javascript, html, css, reactjs

In this link right here, is my code: https://codesandbox.io/s/adoring-joana-8jp8s6?file=/src/Carousel.js:708-2708

Essentially, this code is a circular carousel, that when swiped it turns 72 degrees. It works pretty fine on desktops, and I am very happy with it. The problem is smartphones. When trying on smartphones (Literal smartphones, and not emulating then on the inspect element tool) the animation triggered on the event "OnTouchMove" it's not as smooth as on desktops. I think that occurs because the "OnTouchMove" is triggered fewer times than on desktop. So as a “Countermeasure”, I thought adding a “transition” animation with "all .3s ease” should do the trick, and make transitions between each "OnTouchMove", making it smoother. However, when testing it, I realized that there was some “Flickering”, and that made no sense to me, on why that happened. Also, I have a function, that gets the current rotation of an element. Every time the carousel, while moving, is touched, it should remain in the place where the touch occurred. However, I see flickering and rotation to the wrong location on smartphones. Why does that happen? Is there a way to obtain smoother "OnTouchMove" behavior on smartphones? Also, is there a way where I can get an accurate instant rotation value on smartphones?

Final product in case you want to test on your smartphone:

https://8jp8s6.csb.app/